# Is there a API to get AWS Marketplace Products

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

Is there a Rest API to get products, subscribe to products in [AWS MarketPlace](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace) products?

I was searching for this but had no luck finding anything related to AWS Marketplace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by using aws sdk for node.js

```
var params = {
  DryRun: false || false,
  Owners: ['aws-marketplace'] //show images where Owner is aws-marketplace
};


//EC2 Describe image to get market place images
ec2.describeImages(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

One of the result record

```
{ ImageId: 'ami-001a9130',
       ImageLocation: 'aws-marketplace/turnkey-piwik-12.0-squeeze-x86.ebs_2-f04a7ac8-c067-48f6-872b-c0bb29e4755f-ami-50dd5a39.1',
       State: 'available',
       OwnerId: '679593333241',
       CreationDate: '2013-01-18T19:54:11.000Z',
       Public: true,
       ProductCodes: [Object],
       Architecture: 'i386',
       ImageType: 'machine',
       KernelId: 'aki-dce26fec',
       ImageOwnerAlias: 'aws-marketplace',
       Name: 'turnkey-piwik-12.0-squeeze-x86.ebs_2-f04a7ac8-c067-48f6-872b-c0bb29e4755f-ami-50dd5a39.1',
       Description: 'http://www.turnkeylinux.org/piwik',
       RootDeviceType: 'ebs',
       RootDeviceName: '/dev/sda1',
       BlockDeviceMappings: [Object],
       VirtualizationType: 'paravirtual',
       Tags: [],
       Hypervisor: 'xen' }
```

More filters can be used as explained here:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/EC2.html#describeImages-property